Storing and retreiving data with Milvus and Langchain
I'm trying to create a vector DB which will be populated with embeddings of articles from my employer's blog.
I've got a Milvus instance up and running and am able to follow the walkthrough on the Langchain website.
Based on the walkthrough, my implementation so far looks something like this:
def parseWPDataFile(filename):
    # redacted for brevity
    return {
        'meta': parsed_headers,
        'body': doc_body.strip()
    }

parsed_doc = parseWPDataFile('sample_data.txt')
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(is_separator_regex=True, separators=['\n+'], chunk_size=5000, length_function=len)
docs = text_splitter.create_documents([parsed_doc['body']], [parsed_doc['meta']])
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vector_db = Milvus.from_documents(docs, embeddings, connection_args={"host": "127.0.0.1", "port": "19530"})

This being my first time using a vector database, I'm a little confused by that last line. The documentation for Milvus.from_documents indicates that it creates a vectorstore from documents, I guess, in memory. What I want is a persistent vectorstore that I can load stuff into and then later, in a separate script, pull from. I can't find any Langchain examples of this.
How do I create a persistent VectorStore, add to it, and get a reference to it later, in another script?

I used the Milvus library directly to achieve what I wanted..
First create the DB...
import sys
from pymilvus import connections, Collection, CollectionSchema, FieldSchema, DataType, MilvusClient

# print out some info about the DB and kill the script, so we don't insert duplicate data as this has already been run
client = MilvusClient(uri="http://localhost:19530")
res = client.describe_collection(collection_name="ot_chatbot")
print(res)
sys.exit()


connections.connect(host="localhost",port="19530")

# primary id key
item_id = FieldSchema(
    name="id",
    dtype=DataType.INT64,
    is_primary=True
)

# text field to hold text content of embeddings
text = FieldSchema(
    name="text",
    dtype=DataType.VARCHAR,
    max_length=50000
)

# vector field to hiold embeddings
embeddings = FieldSchema(
    name="embeddings",
    dtype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR,
    dim=1536 # for the "text-embedding-ada-002" embedding model
)

# source of the embedding (id, ourtownamerica.com)
source = FieldSchema(
    name="source",
    dtype=DataType.VARCHAR,
    max_length=20
)

# a URL pointing to the source of the data, if any
url = FieldSchema(
    name="url",
    dtype=DataType.VARCHAR,
    max_length=250
)

# a title, if any, of the wordpress article, for example
title = FieldSchema(
    name="source_title",
    dtype=DataType.VARCHAR,
    max_length=250
)

# define collection schema 
schema = CollectionSchema(
    fields=[item_id, text, embeddings, source, url, title],
    description="OT Chatbot",
    enable_dynamic_field=False,
    auto_id=True
)

# define the collection
collection = Collection(
    name="ot_chatbot",
    schema=schema,
    using='default'
)

# create an index to speed up queries
collection.create_index(
    field_name="embeddings",
    index_params={"metric_type":"IP","index_type":"IVF_FLAT","params":{"nlist":16384}}
)

Then I was able to insert data into the DB like this...
from pymilvus import connections, MilvusClient
import os
import sys
import constants
from langchain_community.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = constants.APIKEY
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-ada-002")
client = MilvusClient(uri="http://localhost:19530")

# Parses the txt documents in wp-data
def parseWPDataFile(filename):
    # redacted for brevity
    return {
        'meta': parsed_headers,
        'body': doc_body.strip()
    }

parsed_doc = parseWPDataFile('sample_data.txt')
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(is_separator_regex=True, separators=['\n+'], chunk_size=50000, length_function=len)
docs = text_splitter.create_documents([parsed_doc['body']], [parsed_doc['meta']])

for doc in docs:
    meta = doc.metadata
    text = doc.page_content
    vector = embeddings.embed_query(text)
    print(vector[:5])
    res = client.insert(
        collection_name="ot_chatbot",
        data=[{
            "text": text,
            "embeddings": vector,
            "source": "wp_site",
            "url": meta['Post URL'],
            "source_title": meta['Post title']
        }]
    )
    print(res)


What the following code does is to establish a connector with a Milvus server at 127.0.0.1:19530, convert the vectors from docs and store them in the Milvus server. The server is responsible to load all that date both in memory as vector index for efficient search and persist in storage so that the data is not never lost.
Milvus.from_documents(docs, embeddings, connection_args={"host": "127.0.0.1", "port": "19530"})
Note that it doesn't create the Milvus server:

The server must be set up in advance, as a docker or k8s deployment, by following instructions (e.g. for docker)
If docker or k8s is too heavy for you, we have the just released Milvus Lite which runs as a python library. By specifying a file instead of network address it will use the Milvus Lite automatically (so you don't need to set up any server before hand). See the code example and a fully-fledged demo. (Just note the integration code is just merged so it takes a day or so for LangChain to release it in latest package.)


I explicitly mentioned in the question that I had the Milvus instancxe set up and running, and you didn't even attempt to answer either of my questions.

In a short word, Milvus.from_documents() persists the data on the Milvus server. It does the same thing as what you did with using the Milvus library directly in the other answer.

That wasn't my question.
